# Microsoft Teams subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Our company now uses ms teams. Whenever an incomming or outgoing call is made the name of the company or customer is not displayed in teams. So I need to display details to that call in a custom app. Therefore I wanted to use the [callRecord subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-callrecord?view=graph-rest-1.0).

But in order to get the subscription working with my app, I need to have an API that gets all the subscription calls and provides the data via websockets to my app, right?

Isn't it possible that the app gets the subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today Microsoft graph change notifications only support delivering the change notifications gtuys webhooks/http post.

If you want those change notifications to be delivered to your front end application via Web sockets, you need to build your own backend solution to receive the change notifications via http post and relay it via Web sockets. Additionally you can request the feature on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com)